# Nginx rewrite directory and exclude a subdirectory

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting, subdirectory, fastcgi

This is my current nginx config file.

```
server {
    listen 6063;

    root /var/www/html/project;
    index index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm-backend.sock;
    }    

    rewrite ^/admin/(.*)$ /admin/index.php break;
}
```

Any access to /admin will rewrite to /admin/index.php.

Now for some reasons I have to add css folder, js folder to /var/www/html/project/admin/includes.

So the new requires is any access to /admin/includes/* will access the real files for css and js. All other access /admin/* (not /admin/includes) will rewrite to /admin/index.php.

Or I can say any access to folder /admin if doesn't exists (like /admin/includes/css/example.css), then rewrite to /admin/index.php

Thanks,

Comment: There's a section in the nginx docs on this. https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/
Have you tried reading it? What attempts stemmed from that?

Comment: For more specific details: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html
To be clear, I didn't know how to do this when I read your question - or where to find this info. I'll come back tomorrow; if there's no answer and you're still stuck, I'll try to answer directly.

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to post a question you should bring a minimum information as a input sample and expected output sample (if needed), what did you try and your research, in order to show some effort, as SO is not a free coding service. What did you try and research?

Comment: Yes, I totall agree. But I did post my solution below after I found the answer. And I think I provided enough information regarding my quesiton.

Answer (score 3):

Nginx uses the longest matching location ([see docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)), so it's enough to give a more specific location directive:

```
server {
    …

    location ~ /admin/css {
    }

    location ~ /admin {
       rewrite (.*)$ /admin/index.php last;
    }
}
```

Then, if anything matches `/admin/css`, it will process only the empty block (and so get served by default), and all that matches `/admin` (and not `/admin/css`) will hit the rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the answer.

```
location /admin {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite (.*)$ /admin/index.php last;
    }
}
```

If any access to folder /admin which doesn't exists ( it is not a real file like css or js files) will rewrite to /admin/index.php.

Comment: Always avoid to use if on nginx, use separate locations instead https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Comment: Yes,what you said is right. But as I mentioned "Now for some reasons I have to add css folder, js folder to /var/www/html/project/admin/includes.".